# Create 2D array from datatable

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a 2D array from a DataTable, however Instead of getting the end result defined below. One row is not added, if that row is added, it will overwrite the column values.

Here is the end result I am looking to get:

```
    [
        //columns
['TaskID','TaskName','StartDate','EndDate','Duration','PercentComplete','Dependecies'],

//rows
        ['Cite','Create bibliography',null,1420649776903,1,20,'Research'], //missing row
        ['Complete','Hand in paper',null,1420908976903,1,0,'Cite,Write'],
        ['Outline','Outline paper',null,1420563376903,1,100,'Research'],
        ['Research','Find sources',1420390576903,1420476976903,null,100,null],
        ['Write','Write paper',null,1420822576903,3,25,'Research,Outline']
    ];
```

However, I get this.

```
[
    ["TaskID","TaskName","StartDate","EndDate","Duration","PercentComplete","Dependecies"],
    ["Complete","Hand in paper",null,1420908976903.0,1,0,"Cite,Write"],
    ["Outline","Outline paper",null,1420563376903.0,1,100,"Research"],
    ["Research","Find sources",1420390576903.0,1420476976903.0,null,100,null],
    ["Write","Write paper",null,1420822576903.0,3,25,"Research,Outline"]

]
```

I have tried:

```
 // define the array size based on the datatable
            object[,] multiDimensionalArry = new Object[breDataTable.Rows.Count, breDataTable.Columns.Count];
            const int columnsArryIndex = 0;

            // populate array with column names
            if (breDataTable.Columns.Count > 0 && breDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // loop around columns
                for (int i = 0; i <= breDataTable.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    // add all the column names
                    multiDimensionalArry[columnsArryIndex, i] = breDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

            }

            // outer loop - loop backwards from the bottom to the top
            // we want to exit the loop, when index == 0 as that is reserved for column names
            for (int j = breDataTable.Rows.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                // get current row items array to loop through
                var rowItem = breDataTable.Rows[j].ItemArray;

                // inner loop - loop through current row items, and add to resulting multi dimensional array
                for (int k = 0; k <= rowItem.Length - 1; k++)
                {
                       multiDimensionalArry[j, k] = rowItem[k];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one row when creating your array since the columns name row dosent count as a row

```
object[,] multiDimensionalArry = new Object[breDataTable.Rows.Count + 1, breDataTable.Columns.Count];
```

And you need to change your for loop to take into count the extra row

```
// outer loop - loop backwards from the bottom to the top
// we want to exit the loop, when index == 0 as that is reserved for column names
for (int j = breDataTable.Rows.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    // get current row items array to loop through
    var rowItem = breDataTable.Rows[j].ItemArray;

    // inner loop - loop through current row items, and add to resulting multi dimensional array
    for (int k = 0; k <= rowItem.Length - 1; k++)
    {
        multiDimensionalArry[j + 1, k] = rowItem[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this is what i was trying to do, friday evening got my brain fried :)